# How to move directory's data to parent path

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem when I move data from a directory to it's parent,
my code:

```
string resDirectory = "d:\\data";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(resDirectory);

if (Directory.Exists(resDirectory))
Directory.Move(di.FullName, di.Root.ToString());
```

but when I run it I get the following error:

```
The parameter is incorrect.
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Have you inspected what `di.FullName` and `di.Root` are when the error occurs? What are they?

Comment: yes, di.FullName return "d:\data" and di.Root return "d:\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) needs a source FOLDER and a destination FOLDER.

Say you want to move the directory `c:\temp` to `d:\asdf`. This will move the contents of the folder AND rename the folder from "temp" to "asdf".

So, how can you move a folder and rename it to `d:\`?

In your example, you can't move the folder up any higher. The folder is already at the root of the drive. You need to move the files inside up higher.

Comment: "You need to move the files inside up higher.", how I can do it?

Comment: Copy each file inside the folder to the appropriate location. See `File.Copy`.